# Prolog Programming loop through a specific fact

Tags: prolog

I am trying to define 4 offsprings charles,andrew,ann,edward in their order of birth.

```
offspring(andrew).
offspring(ann).
offspring(edward).
offspring(charles).

male(charles).
male(andrew).
female(ann).
male(edward).

older(charles,ann).
older(ann,andrew).
older(andrew,edward).

older_than(J,J):-offspring(J).
older_than(H,Y):-older(H,Z),older(Z,Y).

successor_first(W):- forall(offspring(A), older_than(W,A)),offspring(W),male(W).
successor_first(N):- forall(offspring(B), older_than(N,B)),offspring(N),female(N).
```

I am trying to get the succession order where the males who are older succeed first, followed by females who are older. The result of successor_first should return Charles then Andrew, then Edward, then Ann. However, it is returning Andrew,Edward,Charles,Ann.

Comment: There is definitely a problem here: `older_than(J,J):-offspring(J).` What does it mean?

Comment: Are you sure you do not want to represent the offsprings as children of Elisabeth? That would allow to put William into the game.